# Parsing group of rows from many rows

Tags: c#, regex, string, loops

I am trying to parse a group of lines in a string[] that looks like the following:

- junk ....
- Title Mr ..... <-- begin relevant data
- alias johnsmith...
- alias john.smith...
- Salutation ... <-- end relevant data
- junk ...
- junk ....
- Title Mrs ..... <-- begin relevant data
- alias janesmith...
- alias jane.smith...
- Salutation ... <-- end relevant data
- junk ...

I need to extract the info for each group of records...  something like the following:

User.Title
User.alias
User.alias
User.Salutation

I have been trying to figure out how best to handle this, like using a Regex or layered looping, but can't seem to get my head around this.  Has anyone dealt with this before and could provide some suggestions?

Comment: Is it always going to be exactly 2 aliases?  or is user to alias a one to many relationship?

Comment: if the pattern you are looking for is always at the start of a new line, then regex is overkill. Setting up a loop would be enough.

Comment: There will always be a starting "Title" and an ending "Salutation" but the number of alias lines could be many...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just `foreach` the lines and start recording data when `Title` appears untill `Salutation` appears.

Something like:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("c:\\StackOverflow.txt");

List<User> results = new List<User>();
bool titleFound = false;
User current = null;
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    if (line.StartsWith("Title"))
    {
        titleFound = true;
        current = new User { Alias = new List<string>() };
        current.Title = line;
    }

    if (titleFound)
    {
        if (line.StartsWith("alias"))
        {
            current.Alias.Add(line);
        }
        if (line.StartsWith("Salutation"))
        {
            current.Salutation = line;
            results.Add(current);
            titleFound = false;
        }
    }
}


public class User
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<string> Alias  { get; set; }
    public string Salutation  { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I like the way this flows and my testing looks good. One thought...  Would it make sense to hold off initiating the (User)results object until the same time the (User)current is initialized?  This way if no lines match then we don't ever initialize a new (User)results object?   Thank you very much!

Comment: Figured out that in initializing the (User)results within the loop it wipes it out each time a unique group is found...

Answer (score 1):

```
(Title(.*\r\n)+?Salutation)
```

or to use capture groups:

```
(Title (?<Title>.*\r\n)alias (?<Alias>.*\r\n)+?Salutation (?<Salutation>.*))
```

Is the `regex` you need.  After you get this I'd parse to get the object data you want.  But this will get you all the data you need.

Answer (score 1):

A very crude Loop implementation in linqpad:

```
void Main()
{
    var input = new [] {
                            "junk ....",
                            "Title Mr .....",
                            "alias johnsmith...",
                            "alias john.smith...",
                            "Salutation ...",
                            "junk ...",
                            "junk ....",
                            "Title Mrs .....",
                            "alias janesmith...",
                            "alias jane.smith...",
                            "Salutation ...",
                            "junk ..."
                        };

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Count(); i++)
    {
        if(input[i].StartsWith("Title"))
        {
            var tempUser = new user();
            tempUser.Title = input[i];
            i++;
            while(input[i].StartsWith("alias"))
            {
                tempUser.Aliases.Add(input[i]);
                i++;
            }

            if(input[i].StartsWith("Salutation"))
            {
                tempUser.Salutation = input[i];
            }
            tempUser.Dump();
        }
    }
}

public class user
{
    public user()
    {
        Aliases = new List<string>();
    }
    public string Title { get; set;}
    public string Salutation { get; set;}
    public List<string> Aliases { get; set;}
}
```

It doesn't have a lot of error handling and makes some assumptions about your data, but would be a good starting point.

Comment: I like the logic here though it is a little more "wordy" than sa_ddam213's suggestion...  Thank you though!

Comment: I had a thought driving home that you could use the linq operators SkipWhile and TakeWhile